# How can i switch between Slides in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I was wondering if it would be possible to switch from menu to disclaimer by the way they are static images

(I have imported Pygame and im using python 3.2)

```
menu = pygame.image.load('menu.png')
disc = pygame.image.load("disclaimer.png")
pygame.init()

start = True

while (start==True):

        window.fill((white))
        window.blit(menu,(0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.event.get()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        start = False

slide1 = True

while (slide1==True):

    window.fill((white))
    window.blit(disc,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.event.get()
```

Comment: you need `KEYDOWN` instead of `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`

Answer (score 1):

You need `KEYDOWN` instead of `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` to get key pressed.

I made working example - with better organized code

```
import pygame

# === constants ===

SIZE = (800, 600)

WHITE = (255,255,255)

# === functions ===

def display_slide(screen, filename):

    # --- read slide ---

    image = pygame.image.load(filename)

    # --- display ---

    #screen.fill(WHITE)
    screen.blit(image, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- get keypress ---

    running = True

    while running:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        running = False

# === main ===

# --- init ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

# --- slides ---

display_slide(screen, 'menu.png')
display_slide(screen, 'disclaimer.png')

# --- the end ---

pygame.quit()
```